# What is the probability a student can solve 5 of the 7 problems on the exam?

Tags: probability

I have already asked this question on stack but for some strange reason I didn't get enough help/ people didn't respond back so I am asking this again.

A student prepares for an exam by studying a list of 12 problems. She can solve 9 of them. For the exam, the instructor selects 7 problems at random from the 12 on the list given to the students. What is the probability that the student can solve 5 of the 7 problems on the exam?

I am really confused by this problem. My first initial thought was to do:

$$\frac{{7 \choose 5} {5 \choose 2}}{ {12 \choose 7}}$$

I was given a recommendation to account for the last 2 question that weren't answered. I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: Consider the cases where she knows how to solve 4, 5, 6 or 7 of the problems asked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the overlap between the problems selected by the instructor and the ones the student knows how to answer. The instructor may ask 3, 2,1, or 0 out of the problems she asked, and all the other problems in the exam are a subset of those the student can answer. These events are disjoint, so the total probability is the sum of the respective probabilities.